# PHP class reference or copy?

Tags: php, symfony

I drew data from database.

```
$tDate = $repository->findOneBy(array('Key' => $Key)); 

$tempdate = $tDate->getfromDate(); // Datetime class ex 8/30

$tempdate->modify('-2 days'); // deduct 2 days.
```

in twig.

```
{{ tempdate.date | date('n/j') }} // shows 8/28

{{ tempdate.date | date('n/j') }} // shows 8/28 not 8/30 ... why??????
```

Why does second line show 8/28 as well?

I mean it shows 8/30.

Comment: the datetime object is modified in the controller. so in your twig it will stay the same. Other hint is: both lines are the same code, of course they return the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference in PHP.

**Example:**

```
$tempdate = $tDate->getFromDate(); // 8/30
$tempdate2 = $tempdate; // passes reference to the object
$tempdate2->modify('-2 days'); // both objects now contain 8/28
```

This is why the [clone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) operator exists. Here's how it's done:

```
$tempdate2 = clone $tempdate; // clones the object
$tempdate2->modify('-2 days'); // now $tempdate has 8/30, and $tempdate2 has 8/28
```

**Twig:**

```
{{ tempdate.date | date('n/j') }}
{{ tempdate2.date | date('n/j') }}
```